# How can I check why I cannot connect to the database?

Tags: python, docker, flask, pymysql

I have a small school project and I need to build a python web app to track expenses; I want to use Docker and Flask I already have the structure.

I have the following files;

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: cct
      MYSQL_DATABASE: expensetracker_db
      MYSQL_USER: cct
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: cct
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
Flask-JWT-Extended
pymysql
cryptography
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

**create_tables.sql**

```
-- Create the users table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the categories table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-- Create the expenses table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expenses (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    category_id INT,
    user_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

**config.py**

```
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'cctcollege'
    MYSQL_HOST = os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST', 'db')
    MYSQL_PORT = int(os.getenv('MYSQL_PORT', '3307'))
    MYSQL_USER = os.getenv('MYSQL_USER', 'cct')
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'cct')
    MYSQL_DB = os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'expensetracker_db')

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False

def get_config():
    if os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') == 'production':
        return ProductionConfig
    else:
        return DevelopmentConfig
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, create_access_token, jwt_required, get_jwt_identity
import pymysql
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from config.config import get_config
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(get_config())

# Set the logging level to capture all messages
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Create a logger instance for your application
logger = app.logger

try:
    mysql = pymysql.connect(
        host=app.config['MYSQL_HOST'],
        port=app.config['MYSQL_PORT'],
        user=app.config['MYSQL_USER'],
        password=app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
        db=app.config['MYSQL_DB'],
        charset='utf8mb4',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
    logger.info("Database connection established")

# Read and execute the SQL file to create tables
    with app.open_resource('sql/create_tables.sql', mode='r') as f:
        with mysql.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f.read())

    jwt = JWTManager(app)

except Exception as e:
    logger.error("An error occurred during database connection: %s", str(e))

# User model
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, email, password):
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

# Database queries
def get_user(email):
    cursor = mysql.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s", (email,))
    user_data = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.close()
    if user_data:
        return User(user_data['id'], user_data['email'], user_data['password'])
    return None

def create_user(email, password):
    cursor = mysql.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", (email, generate_password_hash(password)))
    mysql.commit()
    cursor.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = get_user(email)
        if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id)
            return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200
        return jsonify({'msg': 'Invalid email or password'}), 401
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        if get_user(email):
            return jsonify({'msg': 'User already exists'}), 400
        create_user(email, password)
        return jsonify({'msg': 'User created successfully'}), 201
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/dashboard')
@jwt_required()
def dashboard():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return render_template('dashboard.html', user=current_user)

@app.route('/expenses')
@jwt_required()
def expenses():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return render_template('expenses.html', user=current_user)

@app.route('/analytics')
@jwt_required()
def analytics():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return render_template('analytics.html', user=current_user)

@app.route('/settings')
@jwt_required()
def settings():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return render_template('settings.html', user=current_user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I have the corresponding templates files for the html but my issue is basically when trying to signup a new user, I get the error NameError: name 'mysql' is not defined but I think it has something to do with the connection, I get this when I run the docker-compose up --build

> ERROR:app:An error occurred during database connection: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

That's for the app service, and in the db service I get this:

> 2023-07-05T14:22:57.590685Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

Both services keep running but I cannot interact with the web application to create users, I think the SQL is not even being executed. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: I believe it is because you have not opened the correct ports in the `docker-compose.yml` file to allow the `app` service to connect to the `db` service.

Comment: Where are you defining variables in Python? It seems the script uses default values because it tries to connect with the root user to localhost and port 3306

Comment: I have a config.py where I define some variables, I will share it.

Comment: Note that your script should be connecting to host `db`, port `3306`. Port publishing does **not** impact container-to-container communication.

Comment: I checked that, but I still cant connect.